# Is there a way to take country two letter alpha codes and display them on a map?

Tags: python, dataframe, maps, geo

I had a DataFrame with country names and values corresponding to them.  I used the following code to convert the countries into codes:

```
import pycountry

input_countries = happiness_data["Country or region"]

countries = {}
for country in pycountry.countries:
    countries[country.name] = country.alpha_2

codes = [countries.get(country, 'Unknown code') for country in input_countries]

print(codes)
```

Which returns this:

```
['FI', 'DK', 'NO', 'IS', 'NL', 'CH', 'SE', 'NZ', 'CA', 'AT', 'AU', 'CR', 'IL', 'LU', 'GB', 'IE', 'DE', 'BE', 'US', 'Unknown code', 'AE', 'MT', 'MX', 'FR', 'Unknown code', 'CL', 'GT', 'SA', 'QA', 'ES', 'PA', 'BR', 'UY', 'SG', 'SV', 'IT', 'BH', 'SK', 'Unknown code', 'PL', 'UZ', 'LT', 'CO', 'SI', 'NI', 'Unknown code', 'AR', 'RO', 'CY', 'EC', 'KW', 'TH', 'LV', 'Unknown code', 'EE', 'JM', 'MU', 'JP', 'HN', 'KZ', 'Unknown code', 'HU', 'PY', 'Unknown code', 'PE', 'PT', 'PK', 'Unknown code', 'PH', 'RS', 'Unknown code', 'LY', 'ME', 'TJ', 'HR', 'HK', 'DO', 'BA', 'TR', 'MY', 'BY', 'GR', 'MN', 'MK', 'NG', 'KG', 'TM', 'DZ', 'MA', 'AZ', 'LB', 'ID', 'CN', 'Unknown code', 'BT', 'CM', 'BG', 'GH', 'Unknown code', 'NP', 'JO', 'BJ', 'Unknown code', 'GA', 'Unknown code', 'ZA', 'AL', 'Unknown code', 'KH', 'Unknown code', 'SN', 'SO', 'NA', 'NE', 'BF', 'AM', 'Unknown code', 'GN', 'GE', 'GM', 'KE', 'MR', 'MZ', 'TN', 'BD', 'IQ', 'Unknown code', 'ML', 'SL', 'LK', 'MM', 'TD', 'UA', 'ET', 'Unknown code', 'UG', 'EG', 'ZM', 'TG', 'IN', 'LR', 'KM', 'MG', 'LS', 'BI', 'ZW', 'HT', 'BW', 'Unknown code', 'MW', 'YE', 'RW', 'Unknown code', 'AF', 'CF', 'SS']
```

I dropped all of the unknown codes, so I only have known codes left.  I want to plot these codes on a map so I can get a visualization of where my data is coming from.  Is there a way to do this?  I tried using `pygal` to no avail.

Thanks for any help and or advice you can give me.  If you want to try this out, feel free to copy that list of countries and make up some random integer values to see if you are able to plot values corresponding to those country labels on a map.  Additionally, if I can just use country names (i.e. "Bangladesh") with a value (i.e. (8)) and plot hues on a map according to that, that would work too.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map your alpha_2 country codes to coordinates using [this list of countries, codes and coordinates](https://gist.github.com/tadast/8827699) then plot your data on a map using any sophisticated plotting libraries, like [matplotlib and cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/intro.html), [matplotlib and geopandas](https://geopandas.org/mapping.html) or – if you want the map interactive and/or for the web – [plotly and mapbox](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-layers/).

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Plotly and Built-in Country and State Geometries

https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/

Comment: Great idea, but I'll admit, I'm still stumped after looking at it for a bit.